# How to concatenate/compose functions in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming

Often I want to do something like the following:

```
sapply(sapply(x, unique),sum)
```

Which I can also write as:

```
sapply(x, function(y) sum(unique(y)))
```

But I don't like to write out the lambda each time. So is there some kind of function that lets me write?

```
sapply(x, concat(sum,unique))
```

And `concat` just concatenates the two functions, thus creates a new one, which executes one after the other.

Comment: There is a function that does this, I can't seem to remember the name though, aargh.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Function-operators#function-composition

Comment: @hadley is the `pryr` package available somewhere? Or is the `functional` package what we need?

Comment: pryr is on github: https://github.com/hadley/pryr/, but functional is fine too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this you can use the `Compose` function in the `functional` package, which is available on CRAN.:

```
library(functional)
sapply(x, Compose(unique,sum))
```

Comment: I've been working with a language called IDL for a while which misses all this functional expressiveness, it is hard to live without for data processing...

Comment: Careful, I think you want Compose(unique, sum). Compose dispatches to Reduce which does a left fold, ie. Compose(f, g)(x) = g(f(x))

Answer (score 5):

## Using [`magrittr`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/)

If we `require(magrittr)`, then we can

```
sapply(x, . %>% unique %>% sum)
```

or even

```
x %>% sapply(. %>% unique %>% sum)
```

or evener

```
x %>% sapply(unique) %>% sapply(sum)
```

To quote from [the documentation](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/):

- `x %>% f` is equivalent to `f(x)`
- `x %>% f(y)` is equivalent to `f(x, y)`
- `x %>% f %>% g %>% h` is equivalent to `h(g(f(x)))`

Answer (score 4):

#### More on Curry'ing and Composing

There is `partial` in package [`pryr`](https://github.com/hadley/pryr) which achieves roughly the same as `Curry` in package `functional` but in a different way.

(`Curry`  creates a list of arguments and feeds it to `do.call`. `partial` literally creates a new function which calls the first function with default arguments set.)

In [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-May/060861.html) discussion in R-devel, Luke Tierney points out some problems with `Curry` (*"This has quite different behavior with respect to evaluation/lazy evaluation than an analogous anonymous function. In addition, do.call has some fairly strange aspect so it with respect to how it interacts with sys.xyz functions, and does not do what you want in many cases I care about when quote = FALSE, as is the default.  Adding this would
create more problems than is solves."*). These issues (however infrequently they might arise) are not a concern with `partial`.

Other approaches to currying / partial function application:

`wargs` in package `dostats` (similar to `partial` but has something distinctive:

```
wargs(mean, na.rm=TRUE)(c(1:5, NA), na.rm=FALSE)
# this works and gives NA as answer, so na.rm=FALSE overrides na.rm=TRUE
# with partial, this would result in an error:
#### formal argument "na.rm" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

There is `%but%` in package `operators` *but* it doesn't work with generic functions. So ...

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:5,NA), b=c(NA, 2:6))
sapply(df, mean %but% list(na.rm=TRUE))
#  a  b 
# NA NA 
# ... but2
sapply(df, sd %but% list(na.rm=TRUE))
#        a        b 
# 1.581139 1.581139
```

And it has a separate mechanism for setting logical arguments:

```
# from the help page
grep %but% "pf"     # grep, with perl and fixed set to TRUE
```

As for compose, there are identically named (but different) versions in both `pryr` and `dostats`: `compose` and `%.%` -- and both are different from `functional:::Compose`.

Finally, I would add that `pryr` includes `f` which one can conveniently use instead of `function` in anonymous functions.

Comment: Abbreviating `function` to `f` is so tempting.

Answer (score 0):

Function `compose` from `purrr` package is a perfect fit:

```
x <- list(a=1:3, b=2, d=rep(1,10))

sapply(sapply(x, unique),sum)
# a b d 
# 6 2 1

library(purrr)
sapply(x, compose(sum, unique))
# a b d 
# 6 2 1
```

Answer (score -2):

You could grow your own:

```
myfunc <- function(y) {
    yu <- unique(y)
    ys <- sum(yu)
    return(ys)
    }
```

Then

```
sapply(x, myfunc)
```

Comment: This defeats the idea of not having to write the lambda, this takes even more code.

Comment: But it's flexible!  I guess I don't know what a lambda is, beyond the Greek letter.

Comment: I know it is flexible, but it is simply not what the OP wanted.

Comment: So the desire is to pipe the output of one function into another function (perhaps several times?) without having to write more than a few characters?  If this exists already, I suppose the OP would already know it.  I guess I misunderstood the question.  Alternative viewpoint: xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: @Bryan Since you cited that XKCD comic I feel obliged to point out that [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (of which `compose` is one) is **the** classical case of a time-saving abstraction: they are trivial to implement and save more time than most other abstractions you can think of (in fact, more than *all* I can think of right now).

Comment: It's not about the characters, it's about conciseness and readability. If I compose two functions, I want to write `compose f1 and f1`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I'm finding this interesting.  `Compose` reminds me a bit of the chain rule in calculus.  I'm going to take a look at the `functional` package and also Hadley's link above.  Simple scripts take the output of one function and put it into another, many functions simply call the next function in line automatically.  I wonder why `Compose` is not used more.